# Javascript Shallow Copy, Deep Copy. Not able to recognize which one is used when

Tags: javascript, web-frontend

So recently i was studying for my interview, I came accross shallow copy and deep copy in javascript, I read some blogs and understood that it can be a huge problem. So i started to learn how to identify them, everything was going great until this example came

In this example, members array contains the original person object after setting it null

```
let person = {name : "Lydia"};
const members = [person];
person = null;

console.log(members);
```

But here when I do this

```
let person = {name : "Lydia"};
const members = [person];
person.name = null;

console.log(members);
```

The member array no longer contains the original object.

Please explain why this is happening, would appreciate any examples and reading material around this, thanks

Comment: “ The member array no longer contains the original object” — Incorrect. It does contain the original object. You just modified the original object.

Comment: `members` is created with the `reference` of the person object. So, if you update `person` object, the change will appear in all the places where it is referenced. Thus you see `person.name` as `null` in `members` after the change. Here, you are not doing any copying. You are referencing. If you want to make a copy, do this `members = [{...person}]`. This makes a shallow copy. If you want to make a deep copy, `members = [structuredClone(person)]`. But, in this case, both copies can be considered as deep copy, as `person` object only has primitive values.

Comment: If `person` has an `address` field, which is an object, then you will see the difference between `shallow copy` and `deep copy`